# Deleting all rows in a pandas dataframe below a row with a specific column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a Pandas dataframe that has extra data in the last handful of rows. I need to identify the row with a particular column value and delete all rows starting with that row and below.

Example of the dataframe:

```
Mod            Day           Initials
 1            9/4/18            AV
 2            4/20/19           AV
 3            7/18/17           AV
 4            12/1/13           AV
Program       Title           Amount
Axis          Axis Gig         $35
Rex           Rex Gig          $75
DOM           Triple Z         $15
```

So, I would want to identify where the dataframe has "Title" in the "Day" Column and delete that row and all rows below it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing with `df.where`

```
s = """Mod,Day,Initials
1,9/4/18,AV
2,4/20/19,AV
3,7/18/17,AV
4,12/1/13,AV
Program,Title,Amount
Axis,Axis Gig,$35
Rex,Rex Gig,$75
DOM,Triple Z,$15"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# select where your col equals 'Title' then fill all other values with nan
# forward fill all nan values after title and the use boolean indexing
new_df = df[df['Day'].where(df['Day'] == 'Title', np.nan).ffill() != 'Title']

  Mod      Day Initials
0   1   9/4/18       AV
1   2  4/20/19       AV
2   3  7/18/17       AV
3   4  12/1/13       AV
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index and only keep everything before that row

```
df = df[0:df[df['Day'] == 'Title'].index[0]]
df
```

Output

```
  Mod      Day Initials
0   1   9/4/18       AV
1   2  4/20/19       AV
2   3  7/18/17       AV
3   4  12/1/13       AV
```

Comment: I am getting the following error: IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. I don't know what is different in your dataframe. I used the dataframe you provided as your data.